# Get string from array of string

Tags: react-native

I want to ask How can I get the array from array of string?

My array is

```
"[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: ‘tem2’,
        value: '934’
        },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: ‘tem’,
        value: '93'
    }

];
"
```

I want something like this:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: ‘tem2’,
        value: '934’
        },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: ‘tem’,
        value: '93'
    }

];
```

Can anyone tell me how to get array from array of string?

Comment: All the answers here are unsolved. And the answer you choose is out of line with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const data =[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "tem2",
    "value": "934"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "tem",
    "value": "93"
  }
]

const stringArray = JSON.stringify(data);
console.log(data);

const dataArray = JSON.parse(stringArray);
console.log(dataArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you want to convert String into JSON array

You should try this:

```
const data = "[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: ‘tem2’,
        value: '934’
        },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: ‘tem’,
        value: '93'
    }

];
"

const dataArray = JSON.parse(data);
```

dataArray is the Array you want!

Comment: Gives error - Unexpected end of JSOn input

Comment: Have you tried removing the semicolon after the end bracket " ] " ?

Comment: "Unexpected end of JSOn input" Error comes when Data is not in proper JSON format.

You need to put String Key and value in Double Quotes. Something like this

`[{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "tem2",
  "value": "934"
 },
 {
  "id": "2",
  "name": "tem",
  "value": "93"
 }

]`

Comment: It says unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: Its working thanks

Answer (score 1):

Convert JSON array to string

```
const stringArray = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
```

Convert string array into JSON

```
const jsonData= JSON.parse(stringArray);
```

Comment: Gives error - Unexpected end of JSOn input

Comment: Remove semicolon from the end of the JSON

Comment: iT IS STILL SAME

Comment: I think your JSON is incorrect JSON format should be like 
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "tem2",
    "value": "934"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "tem",
    "value": "93"
  }
]

Answer (score 0):

Step - 1 : Store the whole array in a variable.

Step - 2 : Parse the variable using `JSON.parse(varName)`

Step - 3: You can also use JSON.Stringify(varName)

Happy coding :)